# Manually Add Twitter Account in Contacts.app in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, contacts, twitter

With Mountain Lion providing integration it is possible to have a contact's twitter username listed as a part of the contact. I don't see any way to manually do this *before* an account has already been added.

There seems to be two separate social media lists available. The first looks like [this](http://dtrnr.in/pi6D).

As you ca see it provides a list of quite a few networks, but no twitter. Once a twitter account has been added a second list seems to become available though, and lists [different networks](http://dtrnr.in/7pMt)

This second list doesn't become available until an account has already been added. Which causes issues if none of your contact's details match with their twitter account, but you *know* their account and would like to add it.

Anyone know of a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at in your first screenshot are the Instant Message fields. The second screenshot shows the so called Profile field. The Profile field seems to be the same as the Twitter field. So, if you want to add a Twitter handle to any contact go to Card > Add Field > Twitter (or Profile). This works even if there's no Twitter match for that contact.

[image]

Alternatively, you can display the Twitter field by default by editing the card Template.